# How to decode PDU messages using VB.net

Tags: vb.net

Is there any one who can help me to find a solution to my GSM modem which gives me PDU answers, so i need a function that converts PDU to normal text.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel you could use the **[SmsToolset](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SmsToolset/)** nuget package which is open source. Its `defaultcoder` class has `Encode` and `Decode` methods which might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you .. i tried but i could not get it working on vb.net